# FireFox SDK keydown / keyup events

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is it possible to track keydown/keyup events in FireFox addons?
I would like to implement something similar as following scenario:

- After pressing and holding the modifier key panel appears
- While holding these modifier keys, pressing the other keys will cause some actions with the panel
- When modifier key released, the panel disappears

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would need to register your event listener in each browser window for that. The high-level SDK API don't give you direct access to the browser window however, you will have to use the low-level modules for that, in particular the (currently undocumented) `sdk/keyboard/observer` module. It allows you to listen to key events in all browser windows, so something like this should work:

```js
// Register key event handlers in each browser window
var {observer} = require("sdk/keyboard/observer");

observer.on("keydown", function(event) {
  // Ignore events that have been handled elsewhere (e.g. by the web page)
  if (event.defaultPrevented)
    return;

  if (...)
    panel.show();
});
observer.on("keyup", function(event) {
  // Ignore events that have been handled elsewhere (e.g. by the web page)
  if (event.defaultPrevented)
    return;

  if (...)
    panel.hide();
});
```

Notes:

- `sdk/keyboard/observer` module is completely undocumented, it might change or go away completely any time.
- Originally the solution proposed here used `WindowTracker` from the `sdk/window-utils` module which is now deprecated. If you really want to look at browser windows yourself you would now use the (also undocumented) `sdk/windows/observer` module which allows listening to `open` and `close` events. The function `isBrowser()` to distinguish browser windows is now available via [`sdk/window/utils` module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/window_utils#isBrowser%28window%29). You would also need to use [`windows()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/window_utils#windows%28%29) to consider already open windows, the windows observer doesn't do that automatically.

Comment: I'm trying this method and for some reason the `key*` events are not fired for the initially opened window(even though it IS tracked with `WindowTracker`) but if I open new window (from the same FF process) then the key events start to fire. Why is that?

Comment: @ak.: Don't know - you probably made a mistake somewhere in the code. Ask a proper question?

Comment: @WladimirPalant can you plz update this answer, it no more works with window-utils being depricated

Comment: @adnankamili: Yes, that's the problem with low-level SDK modules - this API can change at any time. Updated.

Comment: @WladimirPalant If i include the sdk/keyboard/observer in my extension xpi will my addon work even after it goes away completely.