# Add-ons SDK Mozilla Firefox currentURI

Tags: javascript, firefox, mozilla, firefox-addon-sdk

I work with a https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder (Add-ons builder) and I try to do the following things:

1.How to change `currentURI` address? Method `setTabURL()`  is not suitable because immediately opens the URL.

While found a way out:

```
tab.attach ({
    contentScript: "history.pushState ('','', '" + tab.url + "');",
});
```

2.How to get the url address that is entered in the address bar? Method `getTabURL()` only shows the address at which settled.

3.How to add text to an icon in the toolbar? I use it here: https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/166563/

Comment: ok, i solved first and second problem. Thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363708/firefox-sdk-keydown-keyup-events (check element and event.target.value = val)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access the URL bar and it's relate value you have to dig into the browser chrome a bit.

This code snippet will get/set the URL bar value for the currently focused browser window:

```
var wuntils = require('sdk/window/utils');
var document = wuntils.getMostRecentBrowserWindow().document;
// log the current URL bar value
console.log(document.getElementById("urlbar").value);
// change the current URL bar value (this won't change the page)
document.getElementById("urlbar").value = "Thrift Shop";
```

Comment: Yeah, it's a CSS thing.  The Browser CSS sets toolbar button labels to `display:none` normally.  You'll need to add your own CSS that overrides the rule.  Just do something like `#MyAddon .toolbarbutton-text { display: block; }` Use this snippet for loading your stylesheet from the data directory into the browser https://gist.github.com/clarkbw/4999903