# Listen to keydown / keyup events in Firefox extension - addon-sdk

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, firefox-addon

How can we track keydown / keyup events in FireFox addons created using addon-sdk. The solution given on this page is outdated (deprecated) [FireFox SDK keydown / keyup events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363708/firefox-sdk-keydown-keyup-events) I just want to change the value of the variable on key up and key down:

```
// Event handlers
function onKeyDown(event) {
  if (e.keyCode == 45)
    enableAddon = false;
  else
    enableAddon = true;
}
function onKeyUp(event) {
    enableAddon = true;
}
```

I tried something of my own, but I have no idea:

```
var { on, off } = require('sdk/event/core');
var delegate = {

  onLoad: function(window) {
      on(window, "keydown", onKeyDown);
      on(window, "keyup", onKeyUp);
  },
  onUnload: function(window) {

      off(window, "keydown", onKeyDown);
      off(window, "keyup", onKeyUp);
  },
  // what next, how to find and keep track of windows
};
```

Comment: instead of on and off try window.addEeventListener i do this heavily in my addon WorkspaceHopper which you can find here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/workspacehopper/

buts it not sdk its bootstrap

Comment: @Noitidart I actually have a working addon with window.addEeventListener and other stuff - bootstrap, I am porting it to addon-sdk with some additional features, but I can't figure out how to do the same using addon-sdk

Comment: possible duplicate of [FireFox SDK keydown / keyup events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363708/firefox-sdk-keydown-keyup-events)